# COUNTIF returns wrong result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, worksheet-function, sumproduct

[image]
I have 3,900 rows with multiple states listed in each cell. I want to use COUNTIF or SUMPRODUCT to count the number of cells that mention each of the 50 states. The formula I used is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$3896=P3)+0)
```

When I total the number of cells that mention each state, it equals approximately 2,500 (1400 less than it should). I have already done the basics like trim the data and account for cells with <255 characters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use COUNTIF with wildcards.

Comment: I'm not sure if wild cards help with abbreviations because they don't all use the first letters of the name of the state (e.g. MD=Maryland, but MA* would get Maine, Massachusetts and Maryland)

Answer (score 1):

The following array formula works for me (array formulas are entered not using regular *Enter*, but instead *Ctrl + Shift + Enter* )

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(FIND(O2,$C$2:$C$3896),1),0))+SUM(IFERROR(IF(FIND(P2,$C$2:$C$3896),1),0))
```

[image]

Note: you will not find Illinois if only the first letter is capitalized (`Il`) in its abbreviation. The abbreviation should be `IL` in order to find it. The function `FIND` is case sensitive.